# How can I return raw_input to use under a different name?

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm trying to create a `get_input()` function where I can choose how the input is retrieved.

```
def get_input(input_msg = '', getparam = 0, style = 'raw'):
    if style.lower() is 'arcpy':
        return arcpy.GetParameterAsText(getparam)
    if style.lower() is 'raw':
        return raw_input(input_msg)
```

however when I used the method all I got was `None` no matter what the input parameter was. I think this is because the method is imported to the main program so it doesn't actually have access to the parameters.

Then I tried

```
def get_input(style = 'raw'):
    if style.lower() is 'arcpy':
        return arcpy.GetParameterAsText
    if style.lower() is 'raw':
        return raw_input
```

wanting to return the function to use elsewhere and also simplify the inputs for the function, but got the error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

for both settings of the method. `get_input()` seems like it can only return a `NoneType` object in this configuration.

How can I fix this so I am able to call raw_input() or arcpy.GetParameterAsText under a different name?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything if neither `if` condition matches

Comment: Note also you should not use `is` for comparison.

Comment: The fact that you're using `is` for comparison is *why* neither `if` condition matches, and why your function is therefore returning `None`.

Comment: Thanks, I did figure it out eventually.

Comment: "is" operator should be used to check identity. e.g. you have two objects which are pointing to the same memory. '==' operator is used to check equivalence. Like if an integer 5 is equal to 5. For objects you would override the **\_\_eq\_\_** function that '==' uses to determine by your rules if an object is equivalent to another. "is" checks if an object actually is an alias for another.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the `if` statements. `is` should never be used for comparison. Editing my code to

```
def get_input(style = 'raw'):
    if style.lower() == 'raw':
        return raw_input
    if style.lower() == 'arcpy':
        return arcpy.GetParameterAsText
    raise IOError("Invalid Input in 'style': {}".format(style))
```

fixed the problem.